# Is it possible to convert mysql database to Json using native javascript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, ajax, xml

Is it possible to convert mysql database to Json or XML using only javascript/ajax? Or am I forced to use PHP to retrieve the data then echo them before converting them ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use node.js together with the mysql npm package to access your mysql with a javascript only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not until somebody writes an HTTP/JSON plugin for MySQL. MySQL daemon does not currently have anything that can speak HTTP(S), Websocket or some other protocol that the browsers can speak, and deliver the content in the JSON format. The browser does speak native MySQL protocol. So you need some kind of a bridge in between which can be written in any language that can either run inside a web server or provide its own web service and talk to MySQL at the same time (PHP, NodeJS, Python, Perl, Java, C/C++, just about anything).